# Why do I get the PHONE_NUMBER_UNOCCUPIED error when calling auth.signIn in telegram?

Tags: python, api, telegram

I've gotten to the point of sending the `auth.sendCode` method, with the following response:

```
('sentCode: ', {u'req_msg_id': 6324698204597889024L, u'result': {u'type': {u'len
gth': 5}, u'phone_registered': False, u'flags': 6, u'timeout': 120, u'next_type'
: {}, u'phone_code_hash': '52eb4ab096ea211b52'}})
```

This is using the telegram test servers. I have successfully used the same phone number in the telegram iPhone app and desktop application so I know the phone number is valid in production. (should it be valid on the test servers as well?)

When I follow `auth.sendCode` with `auth.signIn` I receive the following error response:

```
('authorization: ', {u'error_message': 'PHONE_NUMBER_UNOCCUPIED', u'error_code':
 400})
```

Is there a step between these two methods that registers the phone number?

Comment: after sending `auth.sendCode` do you receive a code from Telegram?

Comment: Yes. That much is working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from https://core.telegram.org/api/auth

> The auth.sendCode method will also return the phone_registered field,
>   which indicates whether or not the user with this phone number is
>   registered in the system. If phone_registered == boolTrue,
>   authorization requires that auth.signIn be invoked. Otherwise, basic
>   information must be requested from the user and the new user
>   registration method (auth.signUp) must be invoked.
>
> When phone_registered === boolFalse, the auth.signIn method can be
>   used to pre-validate the code entered from the text message. The code
>   was entered correctly if the method returns Error 400
>   PHONE_NUMBER_UNOCCUPIED.

Comment: Once the user is authenticated, how do you save that authentication so the user doesn't have to enter a new code every time they start the client program?

Comment: reuse the session and salt - this is a new question, yes?

Comment: How is this typically accomplished? Write the session data to a file, then read it back in at client startup?

Comment: file, db, your call

Comment: **Thanks, Charles!** Without your help I would still be trying to spell _API_.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure, that your phone is registered, then the reason of this error also could be wrong/incomplete TdLibParameters. That was the case for me in my android project. I ended up with following list, that worked:

```
    parameters.useTestDc = false
    parameters.databaseDirectory = appFolder
    parameters.filesDirectory = appFolder
    parameters.useFileDatabase = false
    parameters.useChatInfoDatabase = false
    parameters.useMessageDatabase = false
    parameters.useSecretChats = false
    parameters.apiId = 1111
    parameters.apiHash = "1111"
    parameters.systemLanguageCode = Locale.getDefault().isO3Language
    parameters.deviceModel = Build.MODEL
    parameters.systemVersion = Build.VERSION.RELEASE.toString()
    parameters.applicationVersion = "0.1"
    parameters.enableStorageOptimizer = true
    parameters.ignoreFileNames = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into [this page](https://github.com/zerobias/telegram-mtproto/issues/206) . So the production phone registration does not apply to test_dc.

As per the explantion on that page:

> use "auth.signUp" instead "auth.signIn"